# Set color of background grid when using a sky package

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders

When I render my scene, a part of the horizon is rendered as black.

I am using a sky package (Pro lighting skies) in order to set the sky but the camera also captures the "grid" background that is rendered as black. By this I mean the part of the canvas that is not overwritten by the sky package.

[image: View of the scene in the editor]

[image: View of the scene after rendering]

How do I set the background that is rendered black in the above image to white without changing the sky?
The sky is set as a property in **world properties -> Surface**.

Comment: Sorry I'm totally confused what are you asking for ... Thanks for more details (in the best included into your question rather than to comment it).